# Oracle Pro*C Precompiler error PCC-S-02201: Encountered the symbol "_Bool"

Tags: c, linux, oracle, gcc, oracle-pro-c

An existing program is being converted from AIX to RedHat Linux. Oracle Pro*C is causing problems upon precompilation. The compilation error occurs with the file `cursesh.h` for the `bool` `typedef`.

The precompilation configuration:

```
sys_include=($ORACLE_HOME/precomp/public,$ORACLE_HOME/precomp/syshdr,/usr/include,/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/include)
ltype=short
define=__x86_64__
```

The includes path is matching with gcc compiler path.

Please help me in resolving the the compilation error. Do I need to include any other preprocessor symbol or missing anything in `sys_include`?

```
Pro*C/C++: Release 12.1.0.1.0 - Production on Thu Jan 23 10:29:54 2014

Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

System default option values taken from: /opt/oracle/product/12.1.0/precomp/admin/pcscfg.cfg

Syntax error at line 374, column 2, file /usr/include/curses.h:
Error at line 374, column 2 in file /usr/include/curses.h
        bool    _notimeout;     /* no time out on function-key entry? */
.1
PCC-S-02201, Encountered the symbol "_Bool" when expecting one of the following:

   } char, const, double, enum, float, int, long, ulong_varchar,
   OCIBFileLocator OCIBlobLocator, OCIClobLocator, OCIDateTime,
   OCIExtProcContext, OCIInterval, OCIRowid, OCIDate, OCINumber,
   OCIRaw, OCIString, short, signed, sql_context, sql_cursor,
   struct, union, unsigned, utext, uvarchar, varchar, void,
   volatile, a typedef name,
```

PCSCFG.CFG:

```
$ more /opt/oracle/product/12.1.0/precomp/admin/pcscfg.cfg

sys_include=($ORACLE_HOME/precomp/public,/usr/include,/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.7/include)
ltype=short
define=__x86_64__
```

Comment: Where is the `_Bool` typedef declared; in your own code or in a system library? My first suspicion would be that your code base has got a system header file copied in, and/or is explicitly including something that is supposed to be conditionally included by another header, and isn't valid or required in your new environment. But really just a guess.

Answer (score 3):

You should add following to your `pcscfg.cfg`

```
code=ansi
```

You can also set the compiler-flag `CODE=ANSI_C` to your PROC-Flags

Comment: Simple and effective for me. I couldn't edit the config file so I passed the option on the command line while invoking proc instead. Thanks a bunch!